# Spring boot doesn't create DB from properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-mongodb

I add this properties to my spring boot application:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=library
```

and write code:

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("Name");
    user.setLastName("LastName");
    User newUser = userService.create(user);
```

But when I save user I have a new DB - `test.users`
But I set DB name `library` in properties. Why spring creates DB with name `test` and doesn't create DB

```
library
```

Comment: Did u set the user ?
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=root

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml?